# Get subresults of majority vote algorithm in Weka

Tags: weka

When using a Weka classifier on a single instance, it returns a classification, e.g.:

```
double classLabel = classifier.classifyInstance(instance);
```

I also the the confidences (e.g. using a RandomForest classifier):

```
double[] confidences = classifier.distributionForInstance(instance);
```

Is there a way to get these same confidences if I am using classifier `Weka.classifiers.meta.vote` which combines several real classifiers?

Answer (score 0):

Cast classifier to Vote, then call getClassifiers():

```
Vote v = (Vote) classifier;
Classifier[] cs = v.getClassifiers();
for (Classifier subclassifier : cs) {
  double[] subconfidences = subclassifier.distributionForInstance(instance);
}
```